# Non-Geometric Proof of Random Normal Projection Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, geometry, normal-distribution

Many papers on locality sensitive hashing, sketching and similar use the following lemma:

> If $r\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a random vector with all entries normally, independently distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are arbitrary vectors, then $\Pr[\text{sign}(r\cdot x)=\text{sign}(r\cdot y)]=\frac{\arccos(x\cdot y)}{\pi}$.

It's not too hard to see why this is correct. It is proved, for example, in [Improved Approximation Algorithms for Maximum Cut and Satisfiability Problems Using Semidefinite Programming](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/PAPERS/maxcut-jacm.pdf) by a simple geometric argument: $r$ is a random plane uniform with respect to rotation. The two signs are equal exactly when they are on the same side of the plane.

What I'm wondering about is whether there is a non-geometric proof. I'm interested in this because I'm wondering what happens if we use another p-stable distribution than the gaussian, e.g. a Cauchy distribution. Such cases don't seem to have as obvious a geometrical interpretation.

Is there a way to prove the lemma just using properties of the normal distribution?

Comment: I think you can compute the probability as $P(\sum_{i}r_i(x_i-y_i) \geq 0) + P(\sum_{i}r_i(x_i-y_i) < 0)$. Now, each of the $r_i(x_i-y_i)$ are normal, if $r_i$ are normal, and their sum is normal as well. I am not sure if similar technique can be applied to other distributions or not though.

Comment: Isn't $\sum_i r_i(x_i-y_i) \geq 0$ a weaker condition than $\sum_i r_i x_i\geq 0\wedge \sum_i r_i y_i\geq 0$?